# How to change the CommandItemDisplay size of RadGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid working well with "+ Add new Record" and "Refresh" buttons placed on the top of the grid:

```
<MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" HorizontalAlign="NotSet"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="True">
```

But the area where those buttons are placed (top) is too big and I can't change the size of it.

Where can I set the property "Height" of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Change **CommandItemStyle-Height** property to convenient size

```
<MasterTableView  CommandItemDisplay="Top" CommandItemStyle-Height="30">
```